# C++ Segmentation Fault in a While Loop

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I have a loop like this:

```
while (k < wordnum) {                                 // wordnum is 9 in my case

    /*There is a text file that includes some words
     *Starting positions of words are kept in wordIndexes
     *Don't worry about not having indexes*/

    //std::ifstream s_words
    s_words.seekg(*(wordIndexes + k) + 1, s_words.beg);
    char *p_Word = new char[16];
    s_words.getline(p_Word,15,'\n');

    //After getting word, they are copied in a struct
    word.id = wordnum - k;
    word.word = new char [strlen(p_Word)];
    strcpy(word.word,p_Word);
    word.wordLength = strlen(p_Word);
    delete[] p_Word;

    //At last, the word is sent for search
    if (verticalSearch(puzzleArray, &word)){
        k++;
        cout<<"Found vertically"<<endl;
        delete[] word.word;
        }
    else if (horizontalSearch(puzzleArray, &word)){
        k++;
        cout<<"Found horizontally"<<endl;
        delete[] word.word;
        }
    else if (diagonalSearch(puzzleArray, &word)){
        k++;
        cout<<"Found Diagon Alley"<<endl;
        delete[] word.word;
        }
    else{
        k++;
        delete[] word.word;
    }   
}
```

I know this is not a well designed code but that's not it. While loop and functions work perfectly until the last loop. When the last loop finishes, instead of getting out of the loop, program gives segmentation error. I'm sure that last word is not causing that because it is found in a right way and returned true. Also I'm sure that none of the words more than 15 characters. At the very last, k++ is working and k becomes 9. Then error comes. I'm using linux so I tried to find where is the problem with gdb and I got this:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7534467 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

I don't know what that means. Do this information help me or should I try something else?

p.s: The program working smoothly in windows.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::string`?

Comment: You `cout<<p_word` after `delete[] p_Word;`. After the `delete[]`, `p_Word` is not valid to access.

Comment: Have tracked the program by the debugger? Otherwise add more code.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but just put delete[] word.word; at the every end of the if-else if statements, you have that code execute in each condition.  Just place it right after the last else branch.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the advice but my objection is making this work without std::string. Also I'm trying to understand why this causes a problem in linux but not on windows.

Comment: @crashmstr Sorry, I forgot to delete that part. I edited it but problem is not solved.

Comment: Should also replace strcpy with strcpy_s(word.word,strlen(p_Word)+1,p_Word);

Comment: _trying to understand why_ you can't understand undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

```
word.word = new char [strlen(p_Word)];
strcpy(word.word,p_Word);
```

You didn't allocate enough space for `word.word`. A string with a string length of 15 characters requires 16 characters to store because C-style strings have a nul terminator to mark their end.

The effect of overwriting the bounds of an allocated memory block are unpredictable and can differ on different platforms.

You are making things extra difficult by not using any of the numerous C++ features that make life simpler and by not having any test coverage. For example, if you had a "string duplicate" function to duplicate the string and had test coverage for that function, you would probably have localized this problem yourself.

Comment: I made it `word.word = new char [strlen(p_Word)+1];` but nothing changed.

Comment: @YunusBurakDurmuş Then read my last paragraph carefully. You probably have so many errors that you need to consider a fundamental change in how your code is structured. Break it into small functions that you can individually test. (Or learn to use a debugger, or learn to use `valgrind`.)

Comment: If you're using c-style strings, please use strdup

Comment: If you do use `strdup`, remember to use `free`, not `delete[]`.